Can content blocker apps see the URLs and content of sites visited in Safari?
In the version history of my content blocker it says it can show the trackers that were blocked. I thought the content blocker apps in iOS don't have access to the URLs that were blocked?
From https://www.guidingtech.com/what-are-safari-content-blockers/:
"Unlike ad blockers, Safari doesn’t access the rules within a content blocker in real-time. That prevents content blockers from profiling users by activity."
"They do not have access to your browsing activity since Safari loads all the rules in advance, hence preventing them from gaining access to sensitive information in any shape or form."
Has the content blocking architecture in iOS changed, now allowing content blocker apps to access the stuff that was blocked?

Which content blocker are you using?

1Blocker, Ad Blocker by Magic Lasso, and AdGuard
